# Create smoothed parallax animation javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

While visiting the [Apple new macbook wireless page](http://www.apple.com/macbook/wireless/), I saw a parallax section (if you search on 'AirDrop' on the site you will find it). Nothing special right, well I thought so to, unless I saw it was smoothed. Let me explain that:
If you have an Apple trackpad or an Apple magic mouse and scroll and abruptly stop the scrolling. The more abrupt you stop it, the further the image will animation.
I also found out that there was an uncompressed version of the responsible javascript, [here](http://images.apple.com/v/macbook/a/scripts/wireless.built.js).

I have been looking and trying to understand how it smoothens it. But I really can't figure it out. It has so much redirections to other modules in the script that I lost it.

I am really fascinated by this animation, because it is pretty complex. But the javascript is probably light and not heavy to execute because it runs easily at 60fps.
So my question is: How does Apple make the animation smooth and especially how does it rely on the speed of the scroll?

I am not looking for a simple jQuery animation on every scroll, because it doesn't rely on the speed of the scroll.

If you search in the code on "265:" you will know where to start.

At "264:" in the proto._draw = function(evt), there is an attribute evt.progress, this is where it calculates the translateY with.

Weird thing though: I could only found a few references to this, but I could't find any link between them.